# Supply of messages in queue to consumer with delay:Weblogic

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I could find way to create delay between supply from producer and consumption by consumer.

But I want to know if there is any possible way to create delay on every message.Say I want my consumer to pick only 1 message every 2 seconds but I want my producer to produce at its best performance rate as my consumer is not as efficient as producer.
So, is there a way to control delay on each message before it is sent from queue to consumer?

I tried `weblogic.jms.extensions.WLMessageProducer producer = 
                    (weblogic.jms.extensions.WLMessageProducer)queueSender;` on producer

and

```
`weblogic.jms.extensions.WLMessage message=(weblogic.jms.extensions.WLMessage)tMessage;
 message.setJMSDeliveryTime(20000);`
```

onmessage but not seeing any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want:

```
((weblogic.jms.extensions.WLMessageProducer)producer).setTimeToDeliver(2000);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/javadocs/weblogic/jms/extensions/WLMessageProducer.html#setTimeToDeliver(long)

I'm not sure what your first attempt was supposed to do. But `setJMSDeliveryTime` has been deprecated since Weblogic 9.

Comment: thanks but I meant that I changed it to this interface and used setTimeToDeliver(), sorry I wasn't explicit. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

there is a bit of a contradiction in your question, in that "consumer to pick only 1 message every 2 seconds" is not the same thing as "control delay on each message before it is sent from queue to consumer". E.g. if your producer was putting in message at say 10,000/hr, and if you put a deal of 30 mins on each message, your consumer would still attempt to consume at 10,000/hr if it could. The only impact of the delay would be that the consumer would not start consuming until 30 mins after the producer started injecting.

Assuming the former is what you want to do, to do this I believe the only option in WebLogic is to implemented something in your consumer code to slow down processing on that side.

Setting `Time` to `Deliver Override` on the queue settings implements a delay for each message, but does not change the rate. You can also set the `Time` to `Deliver` in code from the producer, but the WebLogic queue setting would take precede (override!) if also set.

Hope thats some help!